# How to make Searchable Dropdown like this with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Searchable Dropdown in Microsoft Word]

How to make searchable dropdown in html using any library or simple javascript like this? Because this searchable dropdown is very elegant.

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nukeem/Ubpev/

Comment: Yes this is nice...but this is not what I want.. I want exact dropdown like this...I have seen so many examples of searchable dropdowns but not able to find like this that is developed by **Microsoft** @GokulPP

Comment: Refer https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can try  [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). This plugin contains the element which you want. It is simply jQuery plugin with advanced options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [jqueryui combobox](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html) auto complete plugin as well, the link below gives the functionality and below fiddle also gives a working code

Comment: Yes this is quite beautiful...Using jQuery UI...But I want exact like microsoft word has provided....exact dropdown that we take as <select> and it is searchable

Answer (score 0):

My bet is [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) which can be customised to the extent you want and is easy to learn and use... It also has support for call back function like integrating user input if not present in dropdown.

Comment: You can see a working example on booking form of [this website](http://www.minskairporttransfer.com/) .